# How to review the data entered in a form after the form has been submitted

Tags: php, forms

- I'm working on a proprietary framework
- I have an insert command giving instructions on what to do when the form is submitted. Here the form appearence:
  [image]

**Question is this:**

After I submit the form, how is it possible to create a link redirecting to the form with fields containing the previous entered values in order to review or modify them?

I'm trying using session, but I never usded it and I don't know how to handle it. This is what I wrote in the insert command:

```
$_GET['prefill']=='yes';


    $_SESSION['card_block']['taxCode'] = $record['taxCode'];
    $fields['taxCode']->value = $_SESSION['card_block']['taxCode'];
    
    //$_SESSION['card_block']['num_carta'] = $record['num_carta'];
    echo "<center><a href=http://centre.ccs.local/it/centre_rm/card_block/?_command=insert&prefill=yes><b>MODIFY/REVIEW DATA</b></a></center></br></br></br>";
```

As you can imagine it doesn't work. Grateful for any help

Comment: When you submit the form - you can redirect the user to an HTML page with pre-populated form by using the `header("Location: xxxx");` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `header("Location: Somewhere")` for redirecting.
But I think it's better to set the form's `action` attribute to destination and in the destination page get the field from `$_GET` or `$_POST` array and put them into the new form.

Comment: One of the column in the table is named 'taxCode' (It is a field in the form). I'm using this: $_GET['prefill']=='yes';
 $_SESSION['taxCode'] = $record['taxCode'];
 $fields['taxCode']->value = $_SESSION['taxCode'];

 echo "<center><a href=http://192.168.228.34/it/centre_rm/card_block/?_command=insert&prefill=yes><b>MODIFICA/RIVEDI DATI</b></a></center></br></br></br>"; Is it a right way? Is there a mistake in this block of code?

Comment: I don't see any mistake. You can `print_r` the `$fields` to see what happens.

Comment: I made this: print_r($fields['taxCode']); when submitting the form I read: stdClass Object ( [value] => 1234567890123456 ) The value is correct. But what I need is that when I click on <a href=192.168.228.34/it/centre_rm/card_block/… DATI</b></a> it returns me a form with the field "Codice Fiscale" filled with that value (1234567890123456), but it doesn't happen

Comment: Do you set the `value` attribute of destination field?

Comment: How should I do it? I do this: $fields['taxCode']->value = $_SESSION['taxCode'];

Comment: Field 'taxCode' in my frameworkis defined by: $sf_vaccine['fields']['taxCode'] = new TextField('taxCode');
$sf_vaccine['fields']['taxCode']->label = 'Codice fiscale';
$sf_vaccine['fields']['taxCode']->addFlag(Field::NOT_EMPTY());
$sf_vaccine['sheet']->addField($sf_vaccine['fields']['taxCode']); It is impossible to set the value attribute of destination field